# Could not open JDBC for transaction with Spring Batch

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-batch, mybatis, connection-pooling

Sorry for the poor English, but I hope someone can help me.

I am facing a
`Could not open JDBC for transaction`
error caused by `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` with SpringBatch.

I have a job defined in xml that looks like this

```xml
<batch:job id="chunkJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="chunkJob.step01">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="reader1"
                         processor="processor1"
                         writer="writer1"
                         commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="chunkJob.step02">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="reader2"
                         processor="processor2"
                         writer="writer2"
                         commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="chunkJob.step03">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jobTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="reader3"
                         processor="processor3"
                         writer="writer3"
                         commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Java process is running untill I shut it down by my will, and job runs when I trigger it to run. And I set it to use multiple java thread to run several jobs at the same time.

`jobTransactionManager` is using `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`, database is postgresql, and number of max connection set for pool is `10`.

The error came up when 4 job ran on the same time, but the error won't reproduce every time 4 job runs together.
I was expecting the jdbc-connection to be returned every time the batch-step is completed(committed or rollbacked), so the number of connections that 1 job uses is 1, but since this error came up, I am bit confused.

Can anyone help me understand how and when the jdbc connection is returned to the pool ?

Comment: Do your jobs also create some threats on their own?

Comment: thanks for the response, and no, no nested threads nor transactions found in jobs

Comment: Do your jobs run for a long while?

Comment: jobs are completed by 60~120 seconds, and data-source property `maxWaitMillis` is set to `128000`

Comment: Is it possible that sometimes they take a longer time to complete? 128000 is only slightly greater than 120 seconds. So, if sometimes they take 128 seconds, then it could be a timeout issue.

Comment: with a job like the sample code, does 1 job use 3 connections ? ( 1 connection for each step using transaction-manager)
1 thought a connection was returned to the pool whenever it is committed or rollbacked, so 1 job uses 1 connection as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The number of database connections used in a step depends on a number of parameters, including the type of the step (single-threaded or multi-threaded), as well as the type of item reader (for example the jdbc cursor item reader opens a single connection, while the jdbc paging item reader opens a connection per page). The type of the reader is not described in your question, and without the full stack trace of the error, it is impossible to know the root cause of your issue.

The best way to answer your question is by enabling debug logs for the `org.springframework.jdbc` package.